# In react is there anything like KeyboardAvoidingVİew?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When i click input, keyboard opening on android device and effecting elements height. In react-native there is keyboard-Avoiding-View but in react i didn't find anything like keyboardAvoidingView. What can i do for doesn't effect the height of elements.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should try and program your app to be responsive.
If you did already, it would be helpful if you would've posted your code here so people can assist you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).